# Mysterious shutdown... need help

Tags: sles, unexpected-shutdown

i have a Server (Siemens Primergy Rx 300) with SLES 11 . The Server shuts itself down at 00 : 00 . And I don't know what the reason is. The Installation is fresh (4 days ago) .

And i don't know where to start looking for the reason.
The Shutdown is a regular shutdown.
Maybe someone knows where to start looking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the logs under /var/log for the time immediately prior to the shutdown

Comment: I found the reason in /var/log/messages .... it was pm-profiler . THANKS for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Ask the cleaner what they unplug when there are no sockets free and they need to use the vacuum cleaner :-)

Seriously though, I'd start by having a look at the files in and around /etc/crond.d - look in the scripts for anything that mentions shutdown, poweroff - something like that?

Cheers,
jmi

Answer (score 1):

Is the server connected to a UPS?  If so make sure it's properly sized and has a good battery. I have seen UPS's fail when they do a battery check when the battery is near the end of its life or the UPS is overloaded.

Comment: Some UPS's will also send a shutdown signal to the devices it powers.